# Wordpress get_tags and get_categories by date

Tags: wordpress, get, tags

I am trying to separate the get_tags and get_categories by date. This is the code I am currently using but would like to limit it by years. Can this be done simply? Maybe with a WP_Query?

```
<? 
$tags = get_tags( array('orderby' => 'count', 'order' => 'DESC' , 'include' => '52,67,103') );
foreach ( (array) $tags as $tag ) {
echo '<li><a href="' . get_tag_link ($tag->term_id) . '" rel="tag">' . $tag->name . ' (' . $tag->count . ') </a></li>';
}
?>
```

Comment: You can't order the tags or categories by a date as far as I know. I'm not even sure Wordpress stores this information. You can see what you can put in `orderby` here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_tags

Answer (score 0):

Wp_Query is what you need.

This Query returns posts in the category 'foo' from February 2014

```
   // WP_Query arguments
    $args = array (
        'cat'      => 'foo',
        'year'     => '2014',
        'monthnum' => '2',
    );

    // The Query
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );
```